# Wood worm in a cube

Tags: combinatorics

A woodworm is sitting at the centre of a cube that's divided into 3^3 identical cubelets. The woodworm can go from the centre of one cubelet to the centre of another in any edge-parallel direction. The woodworm would like to eat its way through the cube such that it visits the centre of each cubelet exactly once. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm looking at a Rubik's cube and I can't find any way to do it. Not sure how to prove it though.

Answer (score 4):

Think of checkers. How many cubelets have the colour of the centre cubelet?

Comment: Why does colouring/parity help?

Comment: @almagest: Each move changes colours. There's an odd number of cubelets. You can only do it if the colour you start off in is in the majority.

Comment: @almagest: You seem to be under the erroneous impression that the centre is in the majority.

Comment: Yes, the centre is in the majority. So the colouring argument does not stop a BWBW...BWB path. So colouring does not prove the route is impossible. But if you try to do it, it turns out not to be easy, so I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @almagest: Did you actually count?

Comment: It seems on any ' level ' of the cube , with three levels , if the worm starts in the center or corner , it can complete a circuit ( Hamiltonian ) ..but when it begins on any of the 3 edges between the corners it cannot .and now I solved it ! As painting can be done for the win ;) thanks for the hint joriki

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: The question wasn't about Hamiltonian circuits but about Hamiltonian paths. There can't be Hamiltonian circuits, since the number of cubelets is add so any Hamiltonian path needs to start and end at a cubelet of the majority colour. The centre cubelet is in the minority, so there are no Hamiltonian paths starting or ending there. So I'm afraid you've got it wrong.

Comment: Not really any level is a 3x3 grid . that is the same as what u are saying about majority / minority of painted cublets. I simply put the problem into 2d from 3d .

Comment: And yes I used Hamiltonian circuit incorrectly , as it doesn't apply here . rather when u paint 9 squares of the 3x3 layer / level u will have one more either black or white square . since the worm inevitably will land on an edge , these squares are a ' minority ' in each level . so the worm cannot end on a white square when it starts on one ( here the white squares would be minority brother )

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: No, you can't "put the problem into 2d from 3d". You need to checker the cube as a whole, and the centres of outer layers don't have the same colour as the centre cubelet.

Comment: Times up! Paint each ' level ' of 3 , as a checkerboard . it's a 3x3 grid with four of one color wlog ¥ black = b , white =w ,and the other five another color. no matter how the worm leaves the center it will end up   
On a ' minority ' square ( the four at each level ) and having to traverse every square on this grid of 9. It  must make 8 moves bwbwbwbw, (since it started on a w ) but there are 5 black squares so must end on one ---><----contradiction .$$ it can't do it

Comment: That's what I posted on my Facebook as the answer ..no buddy got it lol ..makes sense to me ;)

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: Well, fortunately mathematics isn't about what makes sense to you but about what's right. I suggest that you try to explicitly specify a Hamiltonian path beginning at the centre; perhaps that will convince you that it's not possible.

Comment: Chill bro . u are correct that this type of problem can't be solved with Hamiltonian methods . only parity and just like the ' mutilated chess board ' famous problem , one must show the paintings of the cubelets lead to an impossible ' knights tour '. Except we have a worm doing ' the tour ' , not a knight ! Lol .where did u find the woodworm cube problem anyway ?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: I don't remember, it's been a long time.

Comment: That's kool . it caught my eye on a separate post . Its very neat . I was wondering if I could see an animation of the worm for an n^3  cube for of course the ns that ' work ' unlike 3 .