# Can a worm eat its way through a $3\cdot3 \cdot3$ cube divided into $27$ cubelets if it starts in the center cube?

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle, hamiltonian-path

I'm an eighth grader working with a graduate student on some math over the summer. He presented me with the following question: We have a cube formed of 27 small, congruent cubes. A worm sits in the central cube, and has the goal of going through every small cube *exactly once*. It can get from one cube to an adjacent cube only through the midpoint of the face; it cannot travel diagonally. Can this be accomplished?

After several attempts at this problem, I have been unable to find a method of solving it, and am currently trying to restrict the possibilities by figuring out which cube or class of cube (corner, center of a face, etc.) the worm has to finish its task in.

Before writing this question, I looked into the wood worm in a cube ([Wood worm in a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750780/wood-worm-in-a-cube?noredirect=1&lq=1)) problem that has already been asked here, but that problem had not in fact been given a clear answer and was closed for lack of important details.

I have been introduced to Hamiltonian Paths and Circuits, but these concern paths starting at a vertex of a graph; not the center.

Comment: This is a puzzle published by Martin Gardner in 1960.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Hamiltonian path starting at one corner and ending at another corner (and, by definition, passing through the center), where the vertexes represent the center of each cubelet:

[image]

But there is no Hamiltonian path that *starts* at the center.